# SlidesJS Slide Id

Tags: jquery

I'm using SlidesJS for a custom products gallery and I have trouble id-ing the current slide.
I've used animationStart:function(current) but when i use navigation is not accurate. The scope of all this is to get some content from the caption of the current slide.

Thanks,
Sorin!

Comment: Can you add sample code, so it clear to other :)

Comment: I've asked a conceptual question. The documentation of SlidesJS is  very poor and I wondered if anyone know or had this problem before

Answer (score 1):

Per the [SlidesJS documentation](http://www.slidesjs.com/#docs) for `animationComplete()`:

```
  $("#slides").slides({
    animationComplete: function(current) {
        console.log(current); // Log the current slide number to the console
    }
  });
```